# How can I synchronize two MS Access tables?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two access tables, Table `TempCost` and Table `FinalCost`

Table `TempCost` has the structure
**ID ExpenseType Year  Jan  Feb  Mar   Apr  May  Jun  July  Aug  Sept  Oct  Nov   Dec** 
1    Hardware        2017 $70 $80    $92   $93 $104   $90    $0       $0     $100 $75  $110  $0
2    Software         2017  $72 $85    $21   $65 $101   $0    $0     $21    $102 $77  $120 $21

Table `FinalCost` has the structure
**ID ExpenseType MonthYear  Cost**
21 Hardware            01/2017    70
22 Hardware            02/2017    80
23 Hardware            03/2017    92

In short `FinalCost` is a more normalized version of `TempCost`, however we need `TempCost` table to  present it to the users to make modifications. I need to sync the two tables so that if an entry is deleted /added from Temp Cost, it should be deleted/added from `FinalCost` and if an entry is updated in `Temp Cost`, it should be updated in `FinalCost`

The primary keys of the two tables are non matching and the number of columns are different. Any guidance on the approach highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a composite natural key linking the tables: ExpenseType and MonthYear. When the row in TempCost is updated you will need to run 12 update queries on your FinalCost table. Create an update query for each month of the year. UPDATE FinalCost WHERE ExpenseType matches the TempCost.ExpenseType, TempCost.Year + the hardcoded month of the query. Assuming your FinalCost.MonthYear column is text and TempCost.Year column is a numeric, it would look something like this:

```
UPDATE FinalCost 
INNER JOIN TempCost ON FinalCost.ExpenseType = TempCost.ExpenseType 
SET FinalCost.Cost = TempCost.Jan
WHERE ((FinalCost.MonthYear= "01/"+ CStr(TempCost.Year)));
```

There are several ways to implement this. You could execute the appropriate month query on exit of each textbox in your TempCost form. Execute all 12 queries when the TempCost record is updated. Write some VBA code to dynamically construct and execute the SQL statement for the appropriate month on exit of a textbox or use a loop to dynamically create and execute the SQL statement for all 12 months at once.

The main takeaway is that you have everything you need to update one table based on the other and it will take a separate query for each month to do it and maybe some type casts along the way to make it work.

Comment: Thanks John, I will try this approach and update the code here once im done.